# Fieldset disabled no longer disables Select2

Tags: angularjs, fieldset, disabled-input, angularjs-select2

I have a fieldset with a lot of inputs under it.
Now when I disable a fieldset, all inputs get disbaled **except** for "select2" inputs.

I did some google and noticed this is a known issue and I'm looking for a elegant solution.

My code looks something like this:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="<condition>">
//lots of inputs
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for that?